# How to calculate speedup and efficiency in a hybrid CPU and GPU algorithm?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, gpu, cpu

I have an algorithm that I have executed in parallel using only CPU and I have achieved a speedup of 30x. That is, an efficiency equal to 0.93 (efficiency = speedup/cores, i.e. 0.93 = 30/32).
Later I added 2 GPUs (Tesla C2075 of 448 cores each) together to the 32 CPU cores. 
To calculate the efficiency including CPUs and GPUs, should I add the amount of GPU cores to the CPU cores? That is, I would calculate the efficiency using 928 cores (32 + 448 + 448 = 928). Or should it be calculated differently?

Speedup and efficiency has been calculated based on what has been said here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/predicting-and-measuring-parallel-performance

Comment: Well, the respectful gentlemen from Intel do not mention **one cardinal thing** - ***the actual costs*** of entering **and** returning from a "parallel"-section(s) -- see more details in >>> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3 and accomodate all respective H2D + D2H + kernel launch + results dequeueing add-on latencies / costs, if having measured but a raw code-execution times. **Not accounting of real-world costs is possible**, yet a sin possible but in academia, not in real business, the less in control-systems or other human-interacting systems. There is no dinner for free,is it?

Answer (score 0):

GPUs have bigger "core complex" architectures called "SM" or "CU" with tens of pipelines each. Not "very" similar to "SIMD" of a CPU, they can issue commands in parallel to these pipelines in a "single-threaded" kernel code.

You have counted "cores" in CPU and not SIMD pipelines (which is 4 to 16 times of number of cores) so, it wouldn't be wrong to count SM units of Nvidia or CU of Amd or Slice subset of Intel etc.

Tesla C2075 has 14 SM units so you could add 14 for each GPU (32+14+14).

If you have also used SIMDified code for CPU, then it wouldn't be wrong to count each pipeline of a GPU which is 32 to 192 times the number of SM/CU(like 448 per GPU of yours) (`32*SIMD_WIDTH + 448 + 448`).

At least this is how I would compute "core efficiency" and "pipeline efficiency". If data transfer to/from GPU is not a bottleneck, efficiency should not drop much after GPUs are added.